# Как обращаться со списком списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Как обращается со списком списков. Например, мне нужны 20 списков из общего списка? Или элемент 40 в списке 1?

```
import numpy as np
img = np.random.rand(60, 400)
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: «элемент 40 в списке 1» — ну прямо так и написать `img[1][40]`

Comment: «20 списков из общего списка» — что это значит?

Comment: если представить списком списков - как матрицу, тогда мне нужно 20 столбцов

Answer (score 1):

`np.random.rand(60, 400)` возвращает не список списков, а двумерный массив numpy ([`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)).

Синтаксис [срезов](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) для numpy массивов такой:

- Взять 40-й элемент из 1-й строки: `img[1, 40]` (хотя и `img[1][40]` будет работать)
- Создать новый массив, состоящий из первых 20 строк исходного массива:
  `img[:20, :]` или `img[:20, ...]` или просто `img[:20]` (но для выборки по столбцам (второму измерению) нужно будет обязательно указать `:` или `...`: `img[:, :20]`)